# Why is my Firebase query giving inconsistent results?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

First question here so forgive me if it's not formatted well.

I'm developing an application using Unity and Firebase. When I try to retrieve data from the database, it seems that randomly there will be no data retrieved when there is data present in the DB. Sometimes (hard to say how often) the exact same code will produce correct results by retrieving the data.

It seems like there's some problem with initialization, because if I call that method once and it doesn't retrieve any data, it will consistently do that until I start a new session. So whatever it does (work or not work) will be consistent during each session.

By the way, when I say "not work" I mean that the "stories" variable has no children. I'm expecting it to have 5 children in this case.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class firebasetest : MonoBehaviour
{
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference dbReference;
    FirebaseAuth user;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {

            user = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

            db = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
            GetStories();
        });
    }

    public void GetStories()
    {
        db.GetReference("stories").OrderByChild("postDate").LimitToFirst(100).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            DataSnapshot stories = task.Result;

            // Create new StoryPanel object for each story retrieved
            foreach (var child in stories.Children)
            {
                Debug.Log(child.Child("title").Value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's what the data looks like

[image: Database Screenshot]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I had this issue before and it seems like Firebase saves an old version of the DB in the cache . You need to use `KeepSynced(true)`
Try this and let me know if this works-

```
 public void GetStories()
{
        DatabaseReference dtr = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("stories");
                dtr.KeepSynced(true); dtr.OrderByChild("postDate").LimitToFirst(100).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        DataSnapshot stories = task.Result;

        // Create new StoryPanel object for each story retrieved
        foreach (var child in stories.Children)
        {
            Debug.Log(child.Child("title").Value);
        }
    });
}
```